# eigs function returns a 'random' result in matlab?

Tags: matlab

The following is what's going on.

```
>> A= [ 0,1,0,0; 1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,0 ];
    [V,D] = eigs(A,1); 
>> V

V =

    0.7071
   -0.7071
         0
   -0.0000

>> D

D =

    -1

>> A= [ 0,1,0,0; 1,0,0,0; 0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,0 ];
    [V,D] = eigs(A,1); 
>> V

V =

   -0.4082
   -0.4082
   -0.0000
   -0.8165

>> D

D =

    1.0000
```

You can see that the same code generates different outputs strangly. So, I tried this:

```
>> [V,D] = eig(A); 
>> V

V =

         0    0.4082    0.7071         0
         0    0.4082   -0.7071         0
         0         0         0    0.0000
    1.0000    0.8165         0   -1.0000

>> D

D =

     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0    -1     0
     0     0     0     0
```

So what do you think? Any idea of what is going on? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `eigs` unless you know what you're doing and need some of the very specific features it has. It uses completely different algorithms compared to `eig` so you should not be surprised to get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eigs(A,n) returns the first n eigenvectors that have the largest magnitude. In this case, both vectors have the same magnitude so are both equally valid answers to the function call.

Comment: I understand. But in this situation, it is not a fixed answer any more, right ?